# Matplot plt.show() runs in infinite loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I call `plt.show()` at the end of my script to display the plot I have drawn using matplotlib, the script stays at `plt.show()` even when the window is closed.

I tried using `break=False`, but then the window immediately closes. I want the script to continue (or stop) after the window closes.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(0.5))
mappable_zmax = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=plt.cm.viridis)
mappable_zmax.set_array(Znew_max)
mappable_zmin = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=plt.cm.viridis)
mappable_zmin.set_array(Znew_min)

# =============
# First subplot
# =============
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(Xnew, Ynew, Znew_max, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.viridis,
            linewidth=0, antialiased=True)
plt.xlabel('Frequency(Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Duty(%)')
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='x', scilimits=(3,3))
plt.title()

# ==============
# Second subplot
# ==============
fig2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
plt.pcolor(Xnew, Ynew, Znew_max, shading='auto')
plt.xlabel('Frequency(Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Duty(%)')
plt.colorbar(mappable_zmax)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Try `plot.show(block=True)`

Comment: Sorry I wrote I tried break=False I meant I tried (block=False) I also tried (block=True). Either way it doesn't work. When (block=True) the script still stays running when I close the figure.

Comment: can you post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?